# Planning for application upgrade which connects to SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2017, upgrade

I am looking for some advise/guidance on how to achieve this with minimum downtime and possibly avoid any errors or failure during production change-

**Background**-

> We have SQL database servers configured as FCI-FCI AG's. That is the
> primary database servers(2nodes FCI) lets call it DB1 (Primary
> replica) is in DC1 and secondary database servers (2nodes FCI) DB12
> (Sec replica) is in DC2 with a database XYZ. We have configured AG
> between 2 replicas and application points to primary via listener LG1.
>
> We have approx 8 application  servers which are on version V2. 4 of
> them are in DC1 and 4 of them in DC2 but they all take traffic at a
> given time and load data for primary SQL database

**Problem**-

Now the ask is that application servers are going through upgrades (Vendor) app from V2 to V6.
Vendor has suggested-

- Remove AG between DB1 and DB2 replica
- Let primary DB1 take the traffic and in the meantime bring secondary DB2 to   write mode
- Perform upgrades on app servers one by one and once all done make all
  related changes on secondary to see if database is in expected state
  while original primary remain unaffected
- If everything looks good make the upgraded secondary become primary
  by pointing all app to this DB2 replica. --> Here i am thinking
  listener will not work anymore because we broke AG in step1, or does
  it?
- I was concerned with data loss in above step because whatever changes
  occurred in DB1 replica would almost be lost because i am not able to
  think of really any way to get them recover and match with changes on
  DB2 unless vendor has some scripts which they confirmed dont. So sort
  of agreed with buisness that they are ok to loose but please suggest
  if i actually can recover?
- Now once upgraded secondary starts taking traffic we will upgrade DC1
  app servers and database servers and make them upgraded with vendor
  package as what we did in DB2. Dc1 app servers should be pointing to DB2 so all 8 app servers taking traffic to upgraded sec replica
- Here at this point vendor simply says to re-establish the AG which i
  am not sure DB2 (if current primary) can actually be in sync with DB1
  replica. I dont think AG can be resync that way and only option which
  i think is take full backup of DB2, diff backup+ tran log backup and
  restore over to DB1
- Once in sync possibly setup the AG back between DB2 and DB1 - Here
  DB2 becomes primary and at this point listener should work and app
  can change connection string to using back listener again. This is
  what i am thinking

Much appreciated here on what you all think and help me here simplify this upgrade so that i can plan this without a real failure. Yes we are going to definitely test in staging env before pushing to prod.

Comment: From that description it does sound like the vendor is misunderstanding how the AGs work.  And it's unclear which parts of the process occur during downtime.